# Как перебрать строку в многомерном масиве С#

Tags: c#

Есть массив который заполняется рандомными числами и если в строке например больше 2 числа которые кратные 4, то их надо заменить на 4

```
double[,] mas2 = new double[20, 20];


   for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            if (j % 4 == 0)
            {
                f++;
                if (f <= 2)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += j.ToString();
                    j = 4;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                textBox1.Text += mas2[i,j].ToString() + " ";
            }
            textBox1.Text += "\r\n";
        }

        textBox4.Text += "\r\n";
    }
```

если менять j то это получается мы меняем индекс, а как поменять только числа в строке?

Comment: _числами и если в строке_ - вот здесь нестыковка, если у вас массив чисел, то о какой строке речь? И почему вы такие операции как деление с остатком выполняете на типе `double`, а не на целых числах, например `int`?

Comment: `и если в строке например больше 2 числа которые кратные ` - значит, делаете проход по строке  (имеется в виду строка массива, да ведь?)  во вложенном цикле

Comment: масив многомерный

Comment: масив как матрица

Comment: Эт мы поняли... Вы умеете обходить двумерный массив по строкам? Ваш второй цикл намекает, что да, но что тогда вызывает трудности?

Comment: ну я через первый цикл перебирал строки, но не пойму как заменить число если там только к индексу считай можно обращаться

Comment: Вот это что такое?  `mas2[i,j]`

Comment: это каким размером будет матрица там 5х3 например

Comment: Почитайте книжку, что ли... У вас же в коде есть обращение к элементу массива ` mas2[i,j].ToString()`

Comment: Прошли по строке, поссчитали элементы, прошли по той же строке снова, исходя из результата подсчета выполнили подмену значений. Готово.

Comment: `if (mas2[i, j] % 4 == 0) mas2[i, j] = 4;`